# If Then Else Statements Regarding Contents of XML File

Tags: xml, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, if-statement

I was wondering what the best way to perform an if/then/else statement with the contents of an XML file.  To be more specific, I want to display one of two images based on the content of a certain filed.  For example, if the contents of a description item is "Red", I want to display a red button.  If it's "Green", then a green image.  This is for a Silverlight WP7 app made in Visual Studio 2010.  Here is the context of my code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => DATABASEinfoList.ItemsSource = list));

        WebClient DB = new WebClient();

        DB.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DATABASEinfo_DownloadStringCompleted);
        DB.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.URL.com/index.xml"));
    }


    void DATABASEinfo_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XElement xmlitem = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        var list = new List<DATABASEinfoViewModel>();

        foreach (XElement item in xmlitem.Element("channel").Elements("item"))
        {
            var title = item.Element("title").Value;
            var description = item.Element("description").Value;


            list.Add(new DATABASEinfoViewModel
            {
                Title = title,
                Description = description,
            });
        }


        DATABASEinfoList.ItemsSource = list;


    }



    public class DATABASEinfoViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (xmlitem.Element("color").Value.Equals("Red")) {
    // ...
}
```